# A sequence of coin flips of random length has n heads. What is the expected value of the sequence's length?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

More rigorously, let's say you are generating sequences of coin flips with a maximum length l, with equal probability of any length from 1 to l. You generate a sequence with n heads. What is the expected value of the sequence's length as l goes to infinity?

I tried this for n=1, where I obtained the probability density function P(x) = x*2^(-x) and an expected value of 3.

For general value of n, I obtained P(x) = x*C(x,n)*2^(-x). Not sure if the sum converges for these, or what the value is.

SOLVED

E(0) = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8... = 1

E(n)+1 = E(n)/2+E(n+1)/2 => E(n+1) = E(n) + 2

Therefore: E(n) = 2n+1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  I suggest starting with some examples using small numbers.

Comment: Hint (for expectation):  Assume the Expectation exists.  Show recursively that $E_n=1+E_{n-1}$.  Existence should not be too hard to demonstrate...the probability of getting a very long sequence with fewer than $n$ Heads goes to $0$ rapidly.

Comment: Should say:  I don't understand your proposed solution.  $E_0$ really can't be $1$...after all, the smallest possible length is $1$, so the only way the expected length could be $1$ is if it was $1$ with probability $1$, but that clearly isn't the case.  Nor do I understand your recursion.  As I mentioned, $E_n=\frac 12\times (1+E_n)+\frac 12\times (1+E_{n-1})\implies E_n=1+E_{n-1}$, though you do still need to argue that $E_n$ actually exists as a finite number.

Comment: @lulu Shouldn't the recursion be $E_n = E_{n-1} + 2$?

Comment: @lulu Simulation confirms $E_n=2n+1$

Comment: @sudeep5221  Yes, of course.  Lost one of the $1's$ somehow.

Comment: @DanielMathias  I did lose a factor of $1$, somehow...but I still can't see $E_0=1$.    I get $E_0=2$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, $E_0=2$. My earlier simulation started with $n=1$.

Comment: @DanielMathias  Though I keep getting $E_1=3$, counter to my (corrected) regression.  Indeed, my incorrect formula appears to give the correct answer in that case, which is why I accepted it so quickly, despite it having been based on an arithmetic blunder.

Comment: @DanielMathias  Doing it out in gory detail, for a fixed maximum length $L$, I get that the expected length, given that you observed exactly one $H$, is $ \frac { (-L^2 - 4 L + 6 (2^L - 1))}{ (2^{L+1}-2-L)}$ which approaches $3$ for large $L$.

Comment: @lulu $E_0=2$, $E_1=3$ and $E_n=E_{n-1}+2$ for $n>1$

Comment: @lulu The peculiar error you made at haste may have resulted from  $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{\ell=n}^\infty \ell{\ell \choose n} 2^{-\ell}}{\sum\limits_{\ell=n}^\infty {\ell \choose n} 2^{-\ell}} =\dfrac{4n+2}{2} =2n+1$.  This would also be correct for $n=0$ if an original length of $0$ was a possibility, giving a conditional expectation of $1$; but if the original length must be at least $1$ then for $n=0$ the expectation would be $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^\infty \ell{\ell \choose n} 2^{-\ell}}{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^\infty {\ell \choose n} 2^{-\ell}} =\dfrac{2}{1} =2$

Comment: @Henry  The recursion is a bit trickier than I thought at first, given the fact that $0$ strings are excluded.  Naively, $E_1=\frac 12\times 1+\frac 12\times (1+E_1)\implies 2E_1=2+E_1\implies E_1=1$, which is false.  For $n>1$, the logic does hold (with the first term now $\frac 12\times (1+E_{n-1})$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a piece of Bayesian analysis, you have

- if the maximum length is $L$
- and the actual length is $\ell \in \{1,2,\ldots,L\}$, each with a prior probability $\mathbb P(\ell)=\frac1{L}$
- and the binomial likelihood of $n$ successes is proportional to ${\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell}$ when $0 \le n \le \ell$
- then the posterior distribution for $\ell$ is $\mathbb P(\ell\mid n)=\dfrac{{\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell}\frac1{L}}{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^L{\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell}\frac1{L}}=\dfrac{{\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell}}{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^L{\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell}}$
- with posterior expectation $\mathbb E(\ell\mid n)=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^L \ell{\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell}}{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^L{\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell}}$ when $n \le L$.

For various small values of $n$ and $L$, this gives

```
  L     1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
n 
0   1.000000 1.333333 1.571429 1.733333 1.838710 1.904762 1.944882 1.968627
1   1.000000 1.500000 1.909091 2.230769 2.473684 2.650000 2.773279 2.856574
2      n/a   2.000000 2.600000 3.125000 3.571429 3.939394 4.232877 4.459227
3      n/a      n/a   3.000000 3.666667 4.272727 4.812500 5.282209 5.680628
4      n/a      n/a       n/a  4.000000 4.714286 5.379310 5.989247 6.539062
5      n/a      n/a       n/a     n/a   5.000000 5.750000 6.459459 7.123077
```

If instead you had allowed the actual length to potentially be $0$, i.e with $\ell \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,L\}$ each with a prior probability $\mathbb P(\ell)=\frac1{L+1}$, then you would get similar results since ${\ell \choose n}=0$ for $0\le \ell <n$ and thus seeing $n>0$ has the effect of excluding $l=0$ from the sums, except that for $n=0$ there would be a positive probability $\ell = 0$, so affecting the lower limit of the sums, and this would change just the top row of the table to

```
  L     0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
n 
0   0.000000 0.333333 0.571429 0.733333 0.838710 0.904762 0.944882 0.968628 0.982388
```

---

You seem to be interested in the limit as $L \to \infty$, in effect giving $\ell$ an improper uniform prior.

- In that case, $\sum\limits_{\ell=n}^\infty \ell{\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell} = 4n+2$ and $\sum\limits_{\ell=n}^\infty {\ell \choose n}2^{-\ell} = 2$, so their ratio is $\mathbb E(\ell\mid n)=\frac{4n+2}{2}=2n+1.$
- For $n=0$ with $\ell=0$ as a possibility, this gives $\mathbb E(\ell\mid n=0)=\frac{\sum\limits_{\ell=0}^\infty \ell\,2^{-\ell}}{\sum\limits_{\ell=0}^\infty 2^{-\ell}}=\frac22=1$.
- If not, then you have $\mathbb E(\ell\mid n=0, \ell>0)=\frac{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^\infty \ell\,2^{-\ell}}{\sum\limits_{\ell=0}^\infty 2^{-\ell}}=\frac21=2$.